# AWS RDS: import data from sql file in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I have a database backup as sql file stored in s3 bucket. How can I import this file to the Aurora RDS directly without downloading it to my PC and import it manually?

Comment: have you tried reversing this: https://serverfault.com/a/903993/353702

Answer (score 2):

- If your data is a valid SQL dump, you can specify its S3 key while creating a new Aurora instance (via the AWS Console wizard or via CLI with `--s3-bucket-name ... --s3-ingestion-role-arn ... --s3-prefix ...` etc.).
- If you want to import CSV, XML or something like that, Aurora MySQL 1.8+ is providing the `LOAD DATA FROM S3`/`LOAD XML FROM S3` query for this purpose.

Comment: I get this "The S3 bucket that you are restoring from must be in the same AWS Region as your Amazon Aurora DB cluster. Check the region and try again" I identified the s3 role and bucket name don't know where to specify s3 key. Any details documentation please? Thanks

Comment: It's `--s3-prefix` (and a text input in the AWS Console, respectively). However, the root cause for this exception is that the S3 bucket was created in a different region than the RDS you're trying to launch.

Comment: it was in a different region and wan't exported using Percona XtraBackup