# AWS RDS: Load XML From S3?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Since AWS Aurora does not support the RDS free tier (it does not have Micro instance support), I am using a MySQL server instead.

I have a script that generates data (currently in XML) that can be imported into MySQL, then writes it to an S3 bucket. I was intending to use the `LOAD XML FROM S3` command [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338397/aws-rds-import-data-from-sql-file-in-s3-bucket/50338630) to import it from the bucket, but I get a syntax error when I try.

I've looked at AWS Data Pipelines, but it seems hard to maintain since, from what I can tell, it only supports CSV, and I would have to edit the SQL query to import the lines manually whenever the structure of the database changes. This is an advantage of XML; `LOAD XML` gets the column names from the file, not the query used.

Does the AWS MySQL (not Aurora) support importing from S3? Or do I have to generate the XML, write it locally and to the bucket, then use `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE` on the local file?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple limitations while importing data in RDS from S3 as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html). Check if any of the below applies to you.

> **Limitations and Recommendations for Importing Backup Files from Amazon S3 to Amazon RDS** The following are some limitations and
>   recommendations for importing backup files from Amazon S3:
>
> 1. You can only import your data to a new DB instance, not an existing
>      DB instance.
> 2. You must use Percona XtraBackup to create the backup of your on-premises database.
> 3. You can't migrate from a source database that has tables defined
>          outside of the default MySQL data directory.
> 4. You can't import a MySQL 5.5 or 8.0 database.
> 5. You can't import an on-premises MySQL 5.6 database to an Amazon RDS
>          MySQL 5.7 or 8.0 database. You can upgrade your DB instance after
>          you complete the import.
> 6. You can't restore databases larger than the maximum database size
>      supported by Amazon RDS for MySQL. For more information about
>      storage limits, see General Purpose SSD Storage and Provisioned IOPS
>      SSD Storage.
> 7. You can't restore from an encrypted source database, but you can
>              restore to an encrypted Amazon RDS DB instance.
> 8. You can't restore from an encrypted backup in the Amazon S3 bucket.
> 9. You can't restore from an Amazon S3 bucket in a different AWS Region
>          than your Amazon RDS DB instance.
> 10. Importing from Amazon S3 is not supported on the db.t2.micro DB
>                instance class. However, you can restore to a different DB instance
>                class, and then change the instance class later. For more
>                information about instance classes, see Hardware Specifications for
>                All Available DB Instance Classes.
> 11. Amazon S3 limits the size of a file uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket
>                to 5 TB. If a backup file exceeds 5 TB, then you must split the
>                backup file into smaller files.
> 12. Amazon RDS limits the number of files uploaded to an Amazon S3
>                bucket to 1 million. If the backup data for your database, including
>                all full and incremental backups, exceeds 1 million files, use a
>                tarball (.tar.gz) file to store full and incremental backup files in
>                the Amazon S3 bucket.
> 13. User accounts are not imported automatically. Save your user
>                accounts from your source database and add them to your new DB
>                instance later.
> 14. Functions are not imported automatically. Save your functions from
>            your source database and add them to your new DB instance later.
> 15. Stored procedures are not imported automatically. Save your stored
>            procedures from your source database and add them to your new DB
>            instance later.
> 16. Time zone information is not imported automatically. Record the
>        time
>            zone information for your source database, and set the time zone of
>            your new DB instance later. For more information, see Local Time
>            Zone for MySQL DB Instances.
> 17. Backward migration is not supported for both major versions and
>            minor versions. For example, you can't migrate from version 5.7 to
>            version 5.6, and you can't migrate from version 5.6.39 to version
>            5.6.37.

Comment: This documentation refers to importing from an existing database instance, using proprietary software. Am I unable to import from a text file like in this documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html